# How to display all the results of a MySQL query when using COUNT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3,
       IF(field4 = 'valuex', COUNT(field4), 0) AS result
FROM tablex;`
```

But even though I have more records that I want to show, it only tells me all of the condition and shows them in a single record.

I need to get the other records of the table and the total value of the condition, not just a **COUNT** result.

Answer (score 0):

You want the conditional as an argument to the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3,
       SUM( field4 = 'valuex') AS result
FROM tablex;
```

This uses a convenient short-cut in MySQL.  A boolean is treated as a number in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Comment: Ok, should I use SUM instead of count?

Comment: For this formulation, you need `SUM()` rather than `COUNT()`.